# Excel - pivot table - update data model

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am working with a pivot table and need the functionality of counting distinct items.  To do this I click the option to 'Add To The Data Model' at the bottom of the 'Insert Pivot Table' dialogue box and everything work fine.

The issue is after I build a pivot table off of the data, how do I add new rows or columns.  With a typical pivot table, I'd Click the analyse tab, select the new data range and hit refresh.

Is there a way to do this for a pivot table where the data has been added to the data model?

Comment: IMO it works the same => Analyze tab, Change Data Source, Change Data Source, select your new range or with the Data-Model you could also choose =>  Analyze tab, Change Data Source, Connenction Properties , Tab Definition, adjust the Command text.

Comment: When I created a new file, and created a Pivot Table from a range and ticked "Add to Data Model", I was able to add columns using "Change Data Source". But if I created another Pivot Table via "From Data Model", I couldn't then use the "Change Data Source" button - the main button was greyed out, and so was the first option in the menu, while "Change Data Source" > "Connection Properties..." just gave me a list of all the connections in my file. Changing the data source for the first pivot table let me use the new range or the old range in the second pivot table - no help if I'd deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it works the same way - if you hit "refresh all" in Data, that should take care of it.